# Retrieve Messenger get_started payload

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a bot setup in messenger and I did set up the get_started button. As per [messenger document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/get-started-button) I executed the cURL to display the get_started button. I did this long back and I don't remember what was the payload I added in the request.
Is there a way I can retrieve and know the payload currently saved? I am not able to find the reference in docs.

Comment: _“I am not able to find the reference in docs”_ - what does it say in the box right on top of the page you linked to …?

Comment: I have access to the docs sir. I am not able to find how to retrieve the properties of the get_started button and the reference for that section in the docs.

Comment: Quote: _“`get_started` is a property of the Messenger Profile API. For information on **retrieving**, setting, updating, and deleting `get_started`, see the Messenger Profile API Reference.”_

Comment: It's a GET request to `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/me/messenger_profile?fields=get_started&access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>`

Answer (score 0):

You can read the messenger profile properties (get_started in this case) like so:

```
curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?fields=get_started&access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

See the docs: [Messenger Platform Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/?locale=en_US#get)